# How to deploy my chaincode in Bluemix

Tags: deployment, ibm-cloud, blockchain

Currently, I have written chaincode following the example. If I want to deploy my chaincode to Bluemix, what are the detailed steps for me to follow?

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: What example were you following? At what point did you encounter a problem?

Answer (score 1):

you can follow this example
https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain/ibmblockchain_tutorials.html

- push to a public repo on github or any git repo service.
- post /registrar with your enrollment
- post /chaincode with json body

```
{
      "jsonrpc": "2.0",
      "method": "deploy",
      "params": {
        "type": 1,
        "chaincodeID": {
          "path": "https://github.com//learn-chaincode/finished"
        },
        "ctorMsg": {
          "function": "init",
          "args": [
            "hi there"
          ]
        },
        "secureContext": ""
      },
      "id": 1
}
```

Comment: And what if I don't want my code to be published publicly?

Comment: @arodriguezdonaire I have no idea but if you run by your network then you can somehow put your code at a node machine and deploy via CLI.